# Django: Add field to model formset

Tags: django, model, field, addition, formset

I can I add fields to a model formset? It seems you can add fields if you user normal formset but not with model formsets (at least it's not the same way). I don't think I should use inline formset either ..?

I want to let users edit their photoalbum (django-photologue). So far I've manage to do this:

```
PhotoFormSet = modelformset_factory(Photo,
                                       exclude=(
                                        'effect',
                                        'caption',
                                        'title_slug',
                                        'crop_from',
                                        'is_public',
                                        'slug',
                                        'tags'
                                       ))

context['gallery_form'] = PhotoFormSet(queryset=self.object.gallery.photos.all())
```

The problem is that I have  to add a **checkbox** for each photo saying "Delete this photo" and a **radio select** saying "Set this to album cover".

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can add fields. Just define a form in the normal way, then tell `modelformset_factory` to use that as the basis for the formset:

```
MyPhotoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    delete_box = forms.BooleanField()

    class Meta:
        model = Photo
        exclude=('effect',
                 'caption',
                 'title_slug',
                 'crop_from',
                 'is_public',
                 'slug',
                 'tags'
                ))

PhotoFormSet = modelformset_factory(Photo, form=MyPhotoForm)
```

Comment: Thank you that did the trick. One last thing, how do I solve the Radio box issue, the radio box is mutal to all photos?

Comment: That's beyond the scope of this question. Ask a separate one and I'll answer there.

Comment: Okey I asked the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4730161/django-using-radio-select-box-on-model-formsets