# Django: Using Radio select box on model formsets

Tags: django, select, radio-button, field, formset

Hey,
I'm using a model formset to let my users edit their photo album. I want to put a Radio select box on every photo saying "Set as cover image" so that I can process all the photos and find the one who should be album cover. The problem is how can I a field with radio select on to the formset and still keep it mutal with the rest of the photos? This is my current code:

```
class ProjectGalleryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    remove_photo = forms.BooleanField()
    # set_as_cover_image = .... ?? <-- what to put?
    class Meta:
        model = Photo
        exclude = (
            'effect',
            'caption',
            'title_slug',
            'crop_from',
            'is_public',
            'slug',
            'tags'
        )
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the key here is that the radio button is not actually part of the formset: it's part of the parent form. It's the actual Album model that needs to know which of the Photo objects is the cover image. So what you want to do is to display each option from the radio button alongside its corresponding line in the Photo formset - and that's the tricky bit, because Django can't render form fields in that way. You'll need to produce the HTML for each option manually.

So, given these forms, and assuming the Album model has a `cover_image` which is a OneToOneField to Photo:

```
class AlbumForm(forms.modelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Album

photo_formset = forms.inlineformset_factory(Album, Photo, form=ProjectGalleryForm)
```

in the template you would do something like:

```
{% for photo_form in photo_formset %}
    <tr><td>
    {% if photo_form.instance.pk %}
        <input type="radio" id="id_cover_image_{{ forloop.counter }}" name="cover_image" value="{{ photo_form.instance.pk }}">
        <label for="id_cover_image_{{ forloop.counter }}">Use as cover image</label>
    {% endif %>
    </td><td>{{ photo_form.as_p }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

I like to have the a neat template file and therefore, I made a custom widget for this purpose.

```
class SingleRadioInput(Input):

    input_type = 'radio'
    def render(self, value, checked, attrs=None):
        output = []
        if value:
            is_cover = ''
            if checked : is_cover = 'checked'
            output.append(
                ('<input type="radio" name="inline" value="%s" %s/>') 
                % (value, is_cover)
            )

        return mark_safe(u''.join(output))
```

Hope it can help someone

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Mikou answer, here is my more comprehensive solution.

In order to keep my template clean and pretty, I used a custom widget

```
class SingleRadioInput(forms.widgets.Input):
input_type = 'radio'
def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
    final_attrs = self.build_attrs(attrs, type=self.input_type)
    output = []
    if name:
        is_checked = ''
        if value:
            is_checked = 'checked'
        output.append(
            ('<input id="%s" type="radio" name="%s" value="%s" %s/>')
            % (final_attrs['id'], final_attrs['name'], final_attrs['instance_id'], is_checked )
        )
    return mark_safe(u''.join(output))
```

My object form looks like that, it will auto select the object if the field `default == True`

```
class ObjectForm(forms.ModelForm):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ObjectForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['default'].widget.attrs.update({'instance_id': self.instance.id, 'name': 'default'})
    if self.instance.default:
        self.fields['default'].widget.attrs.update({'value': True})


class Meta:
    model = MyModel
    fields = ['default']
    widgets = {
        'default': SingleRadioInput(),
    }
```

Here is my formset

```
ProductReferenceFormset = inlineformset_factory(ParentModel, MyModel,
                                            form=ObjectForm,
                                            extra=0, can_delete=False, can_order=False)
```

I gave up handling the save part in the form, it is really not worth the complexity I think... So the save part is in the `form_valid()` in the `View`

```
def form_valid(self, form, price_form):
    form.save()
    # save the default radio
    MyModel.objects.filter(parent=self.object).update(default=False)
    MyModel.objects.filter(id=self.request.POST.get('default')).update(default=True)

    return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

Answer (score 0):

Qualification:

```
<option value='10th' {% if '10th' in i.qf %} selected='select' {% endif %}>10th</option>
<option value='12th' {% if '12th' in i.qf %} selected='select' {% endif %}>12th</option>
<option value='graduted' {% if 'Graduated' in i.qf %} selected='select' {% endif %}>Graduated</option>
 </select>
<br><br>
```